# Cable modem and connectivity issue

Tags: cable-modem

I have new cable modem and moved to a new location. I have Cable point, which attaches itself to the cable modem. Every now and then I realize that my cable modem's either upstream or downstream packet transfer stops functioning. I switch off the modem and turn it on again, it works again. Can I come to the conclusion that Modem is at the fault? Or is it the Cable point or provider fault that is getting manifested in such way that I have do a reboot of the modem for internet to be back online. The diagnostics of the modem do not show any error.

Comment: Have you contacted your ISP for support to verify the modem is compatible with their service?

Comment: Yes, it is compatible. It is listed under supported modems.

Comment: Can you get a listing of your modem's signal levels, both when you're surfing fine, and while the trouble is in progress...?

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the following FAQs from [dslreports.com](http://dslreports.com) and found them to be generally good advice (05/24/13):

http://www.dslreports.com/faq/3361  (how to check cable modem signal levels)

http://www.dslreports.com/faq/5862   (acceptable signal level ranges)